# Error C2440, Battleship C++

Tags: c++, syntax-error

My compiler is telling me that I have an error, but I've e-mailed my instructor and he says my code is perfectly fine.

The error is Error:

> 1   error C4716: 'ShipPlacement' : must return a value, line 139

I'm unsure as to where I went wrong exactly so I'm going to share my code for `ShipPlacement`:

```
ShipPlacement(Coord grid[10][10])
{
    CoordAndBearing SetBowAndDirection();

    CoordAndBearing cab;
    cab = SetBowAndDirection();
    int start;

    if((cab.dir == 3) || (cab.dir == 1))  // GOING HORIZONTAL // 
    {
        if (cab.dir == 3)
            start = cab.bx;
        else
            start = cab.bx - 4;

        for(int i = start; i <= start + 4; i = i + 1)
        {
            grid[i][cab.by].isShip = true;
        }
    } 
    else                       // GOING VERTICAL
    {
        if(cab.dir == 0)
            start = cab.by;
        else
            start = cab.by - 4; 
        for (int i =  start; i <=start + 4; i = i + 1)
        {
            grid[cab.bx][i].isShip = true;
        }
    }
}
```

And here is my `int main`:

```
int main()
{
    srand((unsigned int) time (NULL));

    void ShipPlacement(Coord grid[10][10]);
    Coord grid[10][10]; 

    SetGridParameters(grid);

    ShipPlacement(grid);

    int ammo = 18;
    int hits = 0;
    while (hits < 5 && ammo >0 )
    {
        int x;
        int y;

        DisplayGrid(grid);
        cout << "Ammo left = " << ammo << endl;
        cout << "Enter Coord: " << endl;
        cin >> x >> y;
        ammo= ammo - 1;

        if (grid [x][y].isShip == true)
        {
            hits = hits + 1;
        }
        else 
        {
            cout << " You missed... " << endl;
        }
    }
    DisplayGrid(grid);
    if(hits == 5 )
    {
        cout << "You sunk the U.S.S McCall!!";
    }
    else 
    {
        cout << " You lost "; 
    }


    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You missed to specify the `void` return type for your `ShipPlacement()` function. Some compilers assume `int` in that case and hence the complaint.

Comment: Who instructs the instructors these days?

Answer (score 2):

You've defined the `ShipPlacement` function without a return type. Some (most?) compilers will issue a warning stating they're assuming it returns an `int`, followed by an error since it doesn't.

Just explicitly define it as "returning" `void` (i.e., `void ShipPlacement(Coord grid[10][10])`), and you should be fine.